# Reducer fires and it inadvertently clears input

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am making an API call to one of google API's. For some reason, when the reducer fires, the component's state clears and the input field goes blank. This appears to only happen when the reducer fires. When I just do this.setState nothing clears...

Here is my input component.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
        address: '',
    }
  }

  handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.getCordinates()
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({address: e.target.value})
  }

  getCordinates = (latLng) => {

        this.props.callTimeZoneAPI(lat,lng )

  }


    render() {



    return (
        <input type="text" 
                className="location_input"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={this.state.address}
                onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
                />
```

here is my reducer

```
    const initStateOfTimeZones = {
    TimeZones: [],
    Times: [],
    Date: []
}
switch(type){
    case ADD_TIME_ZONE:


    return assign({}, state, {
        TimeZones: payload
     });


    default:

        return state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your reducer is firing, the component is re-rendering. You are also missing a key assigned to your input so the value is lost on re-render. When the input changes (due to the re-render), that state is updated to match the new input. I've added a key to the input below. If you have multiple inputs, make sure the key's are unique.

```
<input type="text" 
            className="location_input"
            key = "uniqueInputKey"
            onChange={this.onChange}
            value={this.state.address}
            onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
            />
```